# Split code in AngularJS in ViewModels

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mvvm

I have a page with multiple views and viewmodels. Within this page there is a click function which involves two different viewmodels.

Because the item has to go from one view into the other view I have to split the code in order to make the viewmodels communicate with each other. Right now the only way the code works is when I put them together in the same ng-controller(josblistViewModel).

I want to split the code and move the second list to the other ng-controler (timelineViewModel)

Below you can see a quick sketch of what I want to achieve.

[image]

The code I used is:

```
app.controller('joblistViewModel', ['$scope', function ($scope) {


$scope.listA = [{ copies: 5 }, { copies: 2 }, { copies: 7 }, { copies: 4 }, { copies: 3 }, { copies: 6 }];
$scope.listB = [];

$scope.toB = function (item) {
   for (var i = 0; i < item.copies; i++) {
    $scope.listB.push(item);
    }
    $scope.listA.splice($scope.listA.indexOf(item), 1);
    };
}
```

]);

The timelineViewModel.js is empty.
I made a plunker so you can see:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MnxWM7KIjDIOmYIZMUvT?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve that problem. The quickest one is to create a parent controller where you initialize the 2 lists. The 2 child controllers will inherit the scope of the parent and have the two lists in their scope.

```js
app.controller('parentController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.listA = [...];
    $scope.listB = [];
}]);
```

and the html:

```
<div ng-controller="parentController">

    <div ng-controller="joblistViewModel">
        <div ng-repeat="item in listA track by $index" ng-click="toB(item)"><span>Open: {{ item.copies }} x</span></div>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="timelineViewModel">
        <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in listB track by $index"><span>Open: {{ item.copies }} x</span></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4leEQWDv1cmfVw1zz175?p=preview).

Even if this works it would be more maintainable to use directives for the two subviews and pass the two lists as parameters.

You can find an example in the section "Isolating the Scope of a Directive" of this page: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Thank you so much! Couldn't find it anywhere.